# Access login system using a macro

Tags: ms-access, authentication

I have an issue with my code in that when I click on the submit button of my login form, an error comes back.

The error is that "the object doesn't include the automation object 'tbl_tutor.'"

It shows which part of the code is causing the error;

`[Forms]![frm_login]![Username]=[tbl_Tutor]![UserName]`

This part of the code is to check the username in the UserName field of the table tbl_Tutor, however I cannot get it to work.

But I have no idea how to go about fixing the issue. I have two seperate tables for this login system, as there is a teacher and a tutor table and each have a seperate login username and password and are selected on a dropdown on the form, then the username and password are put in, then the form would lookup if the information is correct. My code is probably wrong as I'm not very experienced in Access (this is for my A Level IT exam and we haven't really been taught how to use Access very well).

The full code is shown below;

```vb
If [Forms]![frm_login]![typeselect]="Personal Tutor" Then
 If [Forms]![frm_login]![Username]=[tbl_tutor]![UserName] Then
  If [Forms]![frm_login]![Password]=[tbl_tutor]![Password] Then
   Else MessageBox
    Message Incorrect Username or Password, please try again.
    Beep Yes
    Type None
    Title Username or Password Incorrect
  End If
 End If
End If
```

Then the same is below that for the Teacher table as well.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the VBA code is in the `frmLogin` form, the correct way to reference it is by using the name of the control. Leave out `Forms!frmLogin`.

The reason you are getting an error is because you are trying to access values from the `tbl_tutor` table the wrong way.

Use a `Dlookup` function to access the table.

E.g.: `Dlookup("UserName","tbl-tutor","Username = '" & Me.UserName & "'")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I completely get what you mean and it does seem a bit simple now you point it out haha. I am making this login system using a macro because I can't remember all the code to re-create it in the exam. I put the code into the macro and it came back with an error because it puts square brackets around the Me.UserName and I can't figure out how to fix that.